# VS2010 reference dll is missing from the list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I'm trying to add System.Web.Extensions.dll to my C# console application so I can parse JSON.
I'm using VS2010.

When I right click -> Add reference though it does not list the dll.
However when I search for the file on my computer it does exist.

Please advise on the proper way to add this dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on your project and go to properties.

In the Target framework drop down ensure that you have ".NET Framework 4" selected and not ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".

When you have Client Profile selected it will filter out the server side dlls like System.Web and System.Web.Extensions