# System.web.extensions reference dll is missing from the 2.0 framework .net references in VS2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reference

I'm having a similar problem as this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731282/vs2010-reference-dll-is-missing-from-the-list/5264663).

I'm trying to work with an old project that uses 2.0 framework in visual studio 2010. However it won't recognize that the System.web.extensions dll is part of that framework when it filters to 2.0 framework on the add reference dialog. And no, my framework is just set to ".NET Framework 2.0" as there is no 2.0-client.

Any help would be appreciated.

Right now I just manually went into the csproj file with notepad and added in the reference. This seems to work. Is there a way that I can do this with the other projects I'm working on, or will I just need to manually add it in the csproj files for each one?

Comment: Did that *exist* for 2.0? I thought "not"...

Comment: Yes... It's not "in" .net2.0, if that's what you mean. But when you install it it puts it in the GAC. I would assume that if it doesn't specify "i only work for this such-and-such framework" then .net would show it regardless. Obviously that's not the case. Here's the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en) to where you download it.

Answer (score 14):

I just had this problem with an old project I needed to work on.

I installed version 1.0 of the AJAX web extensions from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=77296 to get the older version of the file, then in my project, I referenced the dll by linking to System.Web.Extensions.dll in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025

Comment: For my project I also had to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.Designer.dll in the folder you identified. Using VS2013 with an old ASP.Net 2.0 project, I first installed Microsoft ASP.Net 2.0 AJAX Extension 1.0, I got a copy of version 20229 of the AjaxControlToolkit (last .Net 2.0 compatible version). I added references to AjaxControlToolkit.dll and to System.Web.Extensions.dll and to System.Web.Extensions.Designer.dll and every built cleanly after that.

Comment: The link was a huge help -- Thanks. This actually worked for me in VS2010 doing nothing other than the install of that "ASPAJAXExtSetup.msi" file. (I didn't have to add the references into the "AjaxControlToolkit-NoSource" project [ver. 20229], must have already been in that particular project.)

Comment: I inherited an old .Net 2.0 project which was last compiled in VS2012 and had valid references to AjaxControlToolkit.dll and System.Web.Extensions.dll. I am using VS2013 and it would not compile, complaining that "namespace AjaxControlToolkit could not be found". All it needed was to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.Designer.dll. Thank you very much @davesol and @Aaron!

Answer (score 5):

The [client profile feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx) was added with VS2008 SP1.  It doesn't go back with client profiles for .NET 2.0 projects.

It seems that the System.Web.Extensions.dll assembly was not part of the GAC when installed - you had to manually include it in your bin directory.  See this [forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1135367.aspx) for people having similar issues.

I would think you should be able to add the assembly by browsing for it when you add a reference instead of having to fire up Notepad and add it in that way.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: It is part of the GAC. And if I manually force it to in the csproj file, it loads it just fine. It just won't look for it in the popup. Here's the abbr. code that I add to the csproj file: 

Class Library: <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />

Web Application: <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
<SpecificVersion=False><HintPath>C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\...</HintPath></Reference>